# Как можно проверить ссылку на вирусы?

Tags: php, безопасность, вирусы

Есть такая потребность как проверить ссылку, которую введет пользователь, на наличие вредоносных показателей, то есть имеется ли на сайте что-то, что способно нанести вред.

Вот как такую вещь реализовать на PHP или хотя бы алгоритм проверки и показатели, которые можно выявить явно и реализовать?
Ходил в google и там есть проверка, но на какие-то сайты просто "Нет данных", а это не годится.

**Update**

Применил **virustotal API**. Ограничения смущают, но платный вариант пойдет

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы имеете ввиду написать самостоятельно, то время, которое вы затратите на анализ и разработку, и в том числе **на поддержку** такой защиты, вряд ли будет соответствовать необходимости и полезности данной функциональности.

Будет проще воспользоваться сторонним API проверки сайтов и покрыть большую часть опасных сайтов, а малую часть принять как погрешность.

Покрыть все сайты **невозможно** и какую-то часть ответственности **стоит переложить на пользователя**, который решил перейти по данной ссылке.

### А есть ли смысл в такой защите для вашего сайта?

**Современные браузеры практический не дают ненести вред устройству** пользователя через выполняемый код, если пользователь придерживается основных правил безопасности и не открывает на мобильном устройстве скачанный apk файл выставляя везде галочку "устанавливать приложения из неизвестных источников".

Крашнуть браузер заполнив память и всякие фишинговые сайты не в счет, первое может быть ошибкой программиста, а во втором случае все основано на глупости пользователя и такие сайты без участия реального человека пользователей не найдет не один сканер.

Если вы создаете какой-то проект, в котором ссылки играют одну из главных ролей (например: поисковая система), наверное в этом есть смысл, чтобы предупредить неопытных пользователей от неправильных действий. В любом случае стоит задуматься, нужно ли вам это?

### Алгоритмы поиска вирусов в WEB

При поиске вирусов в веб выделяют два способа анализа:

- Статический
- Динамический

**Статический анализ** - это поиск вредоносных вставок: код javascript, ссылки на фишинговые страницы и т.п. Это заранее собранная база данных по которой анализируется страница без выполнения действий на ней и если в ней нет заранее определенной сигнатуры, то найти вирус не получится. Нашли сигнатуру или какой-то контент относящийся к вирусу, то пометить его подозрительным или внести в базу.

**Динамический анализ** - это сканер который совершает какие-то действия на странице. Например, робот загружает страницу в разных браузерах, ускоряется внутренний таймер, отслеживаются параметры которые передаются в опасные функции (eval), подменяются referrer и т.д. Тут ваша фантазия не ограничена, можно даже выполнять реальные переходы по сайту нажимая на различные ссылки, но цель одна - заставить вредносный код загрузится, например для показа окна "*Ваш компьютер заблокирован!!! Отправьте миллион рублей иначе щас все данные удалятся!!*"

Для поиска опасного контента применяют комплексный подход, в котором совмещают статический и динамический анализ. Каждая компания использует свой набор алгоритмов для поиска соответствующих опасных сайтов и соответствующие базы данных сигнатур разработаны под конкретный продукт.

### А простую проверку могу я написать? На общих показателях?

Если вы хотите написать простую проверку на фишинг, то можете получать страницу по URL и искать на ней способом статического анализа список заблокированных ссылок или подозрительный контент (*Введите сюда номер карты и утройте доход сейчас! Действительно 10 минут!!!*), но опять же, вам может потребоваться браузер или актуальный JS движок.

Если же проверять страницу на JS вирусы, нужна база сигнатур вирусов JS скриптов, а где ее найти? Я честно говоря вам не смогу ответить. Можно начать составлять самому, но это все довольно трудоемко.

### Открытое программное обеспечение и документация

По алгоритмам поиска и классификации вирусов есть различные статьи, например: [Computer Virus Strate
gies and Detection Methods (2008)](http://www.emis.de/journals/IJOPCM/files/IJOPCM%28vol.1.2.3.S.08%29.pdf), [The New Age of Computer Virus and Their Detection (2012)](http://airccse.org/journal/nsa/0512nsa05.pdf), она могли конечно немного устареть с появлением новых технологий, но базовые принципы никуда не денутся.

Если вам интересно, как работают антивирусные программы, то можете почитать исходный код открытого антивируса [ClamAv](https://www.clamav.net/), есть энтузиасты которые написали на основе его баз сигнатур обертку [PhpMussel](https://github.com/phpMussel/phpMussel) или поискать на Github проекты по названию anti-virus, virus detection и т.д.

### Выводы

Легко распознать все вирусы не получится - это очень комплексная задача и существует огромное количество способов сделать это.

**Вы попадаете в бесконечную игру**, в которой авторы вредоносных программ создают новые приемы, а вы должны совершенствовать способы их обнаружения, иначе алгоритм вашей защиты через какое-то время станет не актуальным.

Неплохой агрегатор существующих сервисов проверки [Virustotal](https://www.virustotal.com), в нем можно выполнять до 4 запросов в минуту бесплатно по состоянию на 2018 год и проверять сайт по многим базам одним запросом.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Писать самому - утопия. Практиковаться - отлично. Я смотрю в сторону virustotal API. Цель такая: сделать ресурс (для себя) по коротким ссылкам. Не хотелось бы, чтобы (если давать на интеграцию) добавляли вирусы и тд..